# Database Administrators Moderator Business Cards

Tags: discussion, design

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place.

If you're a dba.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Database Administrators Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to your fellow DBAs during local meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: dba.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/email/phone are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL, etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Yes! I would love one. ♦

Answer (score 4):

So I'm not sure if we four are supposed to answer or what. I would certainly find it useful, and in point of fact was pinged when this was posted ;-)

So ... what are we supposed to do going forward?

Comment: Upvote this question, tell me whether you'd find them useful, await an email with instructions... you can also dance around the room if you're that way inclined. ;)

Comment: Done then ;-) :D

Comment: Hell yes! <15 chars>

Comment: i upvoted this even though i'm not a moderator. i believe that there's hard work put forth by the moderators and they deserve recognition for it! keep up the good work! :)